# how to change behavior of buttons in win8

Tags: user-interface, windows-8

I am writing an application for win8.
On my MainPage there are some buttons, just like on a WPF window.
When I enter (point) on any of the buttons their background becomes the background of the grid they are inside. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default colors of controls if you override them in the `App.xaml` file.

You can find [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/957b333f-035f-448e-9f4a-213d1290ee51/indeterminate-progressbar-foreground-dosent-work) a pretty big list of all customizations you can do to controls, with such method.

Just change in App.xaml, what you need, like this :

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <!-- Button colors change-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="yourColorHere" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Note that these changes are made at the level of the entire App. This means, you can't use two customizations for the same control.